# Verifying model identifiability via simulations

Tags: mixed-model, simulation, lme4-nlme, identifiability

I'm working on a nonlinear mixed effects model with 4 parameters. I've simulated some data to fit my model to, and I would like to check that the model is identifiable. I'm trying to outline some approaches that I can use to check this

If no 2 distinct sets of parameters can give rise to the same log-likelihood for an identifiable model, would it make sense to simulate N data sets, fit the model N times, save the parameter estimates and log-likelihood from each model, and then see if two sets of parameter estimates give rise to the same log-likelihood? I was thinking of plotting the parameter estimates and log-likelihood values for 1000 data sets...would that be an intuitive way to visualize this?

Should I also try holding one or a combination of parameters constant and then fitting the model? Would this help me narrow down which parameters may be unidentifiable?